# Non-negative Matrix Factorization applied to PET images

Tags: non-negative-matrix-factorization

for my master thesis work I have to analyze some brain PETs of patients affected by gliomas. Basically the problem is: I have a 3D scale of gray image of the brain. The tumor zone is an high-intensity one and so is white. I would like to segmentate the tumor region. The problem is that also another anatomical region is white (bases nuclei) and there is a white background (noise) over all the image. I would like to separate the three contributions (tumor, background, bases nuclei). The position of the tumors vary in different PETs. So, could NMF be a good way to solve this problem? Should it be capable of extract the various feature? Given X=WH the nmf, I would like to find in a W column a 3d image of the tumor, do you think its feasible? I tried with a low number of data (20 PET) and failed... Don't know if the problem is the low amount of data or the nmf itself which is not indicated for this problem ...